# Property not found although it should be

Tags: objective-c

This is a weird bug.

I have this in the header:

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"

@interface ProxyProfileObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *profileName;
    NSString *ipAddress;
    NSString *port;
}

-(void) setProfileName:(NSString *)string;
-(NSString*) getProfileName;
-(void) setIP:(NSString *)string;
-(NSString*) getIP;
-(void) setPort:(NSString *)string;
-(NSString*) getPort;

@end
```

And this in the implementation:

```
#import "ProxyProfileObject.h"

@interface ProxyProfileObject()

@end

@implementation ProxyProfileObject

-(void) setProfileName:(NSString *)string{
    profileName = string;
}

-(NSString*) getProfileName{
    return profileName;
}

-(void) setIP:(NSString *)string{
    ipAddress = string;
}

-(NSString*) getIP{
    return ipAddress;
}

-(void) setPort:(NSString *)string{
    port = string;
}

-(NSString*) getPort{
    return port;
}

// Encoding stuff
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.profileName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"profileName"];
        self.port = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"port"];
        self.ipAddress = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ip"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:profileName forKey:@"profileName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:ipAddress forKey:@"ip"];
    [encoder encodeObject:port forKey:@"port"];

}

@end
```

I am not sure why it does this. It shouldn't do it as ipAddress is the same thing as port or profile name.

Those are the two files. You can now see by yourself how ipAddress doesn't work.

Comment: you use **profileName** not **profile** so why compare with **ip** which isn't **ipAddress** , also building doesn't mean compiler accespts the string inside "" it's a runtime issue

Comment: FYI - this is written like 15 year-old Objective-C code. You really should use modern Objective-C. Declare properties, not ivars and explicit setter/getter methods. It will save you a lot of grunt work and errors.

Comment: Not only is that in the style of 15 year old objc, it isn't a style that was ever used.  ObjC **never** uses `get` prefixes on simple accessor methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your header `NSString *ipAddress` declares an ivar.
- I the implementation `self.ipAddress` refers to a property.
- You declared no such property. Hence the error.

**After the edit** your problem becomes apparent:

You do not declare a method `-(void)setIpAddress:(NSString *)address;`

That's what would make Xcode allow you to use property syntax (dot notation) for the setter—even though it's not an actual property.

Comment: I am not sure I understand? ipAddress is implemented in the same way I implemented port and profilename. Why do they work and it doesnt?

Comment: They don't. If you don't see errors for the other properties it's something else in your project.

Comment: Yep they work. I used this exact way for two other objects and it worked wonders. It just doesn't work with ipAddress.

Comment: As I said, that's something else then. Maybe you declare the properties elsewhere. Try to setup a fresh project and paste the code you pasted above.

Comment: Added the full code. Doesn't change much (apart from the getters and setters).

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring instance variables, not properties. Just put the `@property` directive in front of the lines.

```
@interface ProxyProfileObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {}
@property NSString *profileName;
@property NSString *ipAddress;
@property NSString *port;
```

Edit: Don't write explicit getters and setters. Use the (error-free) synthesized accessors provided by the `@property` declaration.

Comment: Same thing I asked Nikolai, why does profileName and port work without errors? I have used the method in my post with success before. It just doesn't work with ipAddress.